# Redux state with better structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have the following react-redux state:

```
{
  response: {
    json: [],
    waitingForResponse: false,
    communicationError: false,
    searchButtonDisabled: true
  },
  routing: {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to have a state with better structure, something like this:

```
{
  app: {
      home: {
          searchButtonDisabled: true
      },
      warning: {
          waitingForResponse: false,
          communicationError: false
      },
      rest: {
          json: [],
          httpStatus: 200
      }
  },

  routing: ...
}
```

I guess I need to do some magic with store definition. My current App.js file looks like this

```
const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        response: reducer,
        routing: routerReducer
    }),
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```

Does it make sense to build this structure or it just makes my code more complicated without any additional benefit?

If it is not a good idea then I can add some prefixes before the name of the original properties:

```
{
  response: {
    restJson: [],
    restHttpStatus: 200,

    warningWaitingForResponse: false,
    warningCommunicationError: false,

    homeSearchButtonDisabled: true
  },
  routing: {
    locationBeforeTransitions: {
      pathname: '/hello/',
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

What is the best practice to build a bigger state component?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normalizing (keeping it flat as possible) will make your life easier in the long run, though there is no hard and fast rule.

Official docs about it:
http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Mark Erikson has written a tonne of good stuff on it already:
https://hashnode.com/post/what-are-the-best-practices-when-normalizing-redux-data-cive6wc8b08aj3853mvjpfsh1

Comment: Heh, thanks!  Just happy to see that the stuff I've written is proving useful for people :)